# image cannot display even url is set into imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

This is my activity.

```
private ImageLoader testing;
testing = new ImageLoader(this);
imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_alllatestnewstitle);
...
...
...
```

This is in listview, so it will display multiple images.

```
private void filldata() {
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    String[] from = new String[] { "particularlatestnewstitle",
            "newscategorytitle", "newsdate" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text_particularlatestnewstitle,
            R.id.text_newscategorytitle, R.id.text_newsdate };

    fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < webservice.news.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("particularlatestnewstitle", webservice.news.get(i)
                .getNtitle());
        map.put("newscategorytitle", webservice.news.get(i).getNewCatName());
        map.put("newsdate", webservice.news.get(i).getNArticalD());

        fillMaps.add(map);
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_alllatestnewstitle);
        imageview.setTag(imagepath[i]);
        testing.DisplayImage(imagepath[i], imageview);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps,
            R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, from, to);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my ImageLoader class

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null){
        System.out.println(url.toString());
        System.out.println(bitmap.toString());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
    }
}
```

This is the xml layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_alllatestnewstitle"
    android:layout_width="134px"
    android:layout_height="80px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

I was print the result

```
url and bitmap
```

Both not null and display correct url link.

But when setimagebitmap, it got no error but the imageview also did not display the image.

What is the problem?

p/s: Request for more code if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you are using Lazy loading logic of Fedor.

And now, based on the code you have provided i can say one thing, i.e. You forgot to set TAG to your ImageView before calling DisplayImage() method.

```
testing.setTag(imagepath[i]);
```

Comment: ImageLoader don't have this function

Comment: @AlanLai FYI, its built-in function.

Comment: how to call it?

it should not be testing

Comment: i mean imageView.setTag("URL of the image")

Comment: i don't have getview() method, i am using simpleadapter built in function

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code for `donwload image` and set image in `imageview`.

```
       try {
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if(bitmap!=null){
                System.out.println(url.toString());
                System.out.println(bitmap.toString());
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i was change from this to current this one

Comment: this is because this one cannot load multiple image into listview, it will cause outofmemory

Comment: use lazy loading concepts with listview may be solw your problem.

Comment: OutOfMemory occurs because of limited Virtual Memory in emulator. If Image with high size then problem of outofmemory so First Download images and save temp in some folder in SDCard and then use that image with compression of that image with required size and density.